# php get multidimensional array value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
'application_noreply_email' => array(
    'name' => 'example.com',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'connection_class' => 'login',
    'port' => '587',
    'connection_config' => array(
        'ssl' => 'tls',
        'username' => 'username@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'pass',
    ),
),
```

How can i get the value of username?

I have tried using it like this, as you suggeste but it doesnt work.

```
$config['application_noreply_email']['username']
```

but this works in different situations `$config['application_noreply_email']`

Comment: Have you read official manual? (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a series of bracketed key names:

```
$application_noreply_email['connection_config']['username']
```

From the way you formatted your question, it looks like `application_noreply_email` may be a key in a larger array, in which case you would do this:

```
$theArrayVariableName['application_noreply_email']['connection_config']['username']
```

Comment: Thanks, the second one is correct answer, i have already tried the first one but it failed. I will select this as answer soon.

Answer (score 2):

If your array is called `$myarray`, then

```
$username = $myarray['application_noreply_email']['connection_config']['username'];
```

Answer (score 1):

First question is what is the variable that is holding the array?

Example

```
$myArray = array(
  'application_noreply_email' => array(
  'name' => 'example.com',
  'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  'connection_class' => 'login',
  'port' => '587',
  'connection_config' => array(
    'ssl' => 'tls',
    'username' => 'username@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'pass',
  ),
);

print $myArray['application_noreply_email']['connection_config']['username'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want get information, you must loop through the array and display it.

```
foreach ( $application_noreply_email as $application) {

  echo '<dl style="margin-bottom: 1em;">';

  foreach ( $application as $key => $value ) {
    echo "<dt>$key</dt><dd>$value</dd>";
  }

  echo '</dl>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide more data but this below will be able to help you.

```
echo $myarray[0]['username'];
```